# Showing information from Linux OS kernel as Android notification

Tags: android, notifications, kernel, hal

I'm trying to show kernel events as an Android notification.
For instance, USB device-related information will be shown to the user when a new USB device is plugged into the smartphone (similarly to the iPhone USB notification when the phone is connected to the PC).

Because there are several layers between Linux kernel and Android (e.g., HAL and  Android runtime), what I'm trying to do might require adding new components or revising the Android framework. That is, I need to find a way to bridge between Linux and JAVA (Android runtime).

Hence my question is as follows.

(1) Is it possible to push some kernel information to an existing component to deliver the information to the Android layer? For instance, the information will be sent to the kernel driver that is referenced by Android (e.g., HAL), which collects kernel events for user notification.

(2) If I need to add new components, what the expected changes (e.g., HAL and libraries) are? Please advise me for a starting point to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is USB plugged in, you're GREATLY overcomplicating things.  Just create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED and your app will be informed of USB attach events.  ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED is the matching one for detatchments.

Comment: I need to show the information before it is actually attached to the smart phone (during the device probing). After getting user’s permission, the attachment process will be continued.

Comment: I assume you're doing this for a custom OS?  Because that's never something you'll get to work on an already installed version

Comment: Yes, it will be developed on open source Android platform (development board).